# show images uploaded by admin in html template

Tags: django

I am new to django and I saw solutions for my problem but none worked.

I make admin upload images as you see in Item class in models.py :

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib import admin


class Customer (models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=1000 , unique=True)
    phone = models.IntegerField()
    address = models.CharField(max_length=3000)


class Category(models.Model):
    category_title = models.CharField(max_length=100 , unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.category_title


class Order (models.Model):
    time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    total = models.IntegerField()
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(Customer, related_name='orders')


class Item (models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100 ,unique=True)
    details = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    item_logo = models.ImageField(upload_to='res/static/res/images')
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name="items" ,on_delete= models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class ItemInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Item

class CategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        ItemInline,
    ]
```

so how can I make those images appear in my HTML ( note: html code works fine but a small default image field appear instead of image ) :

```
{% extends 'res/menu.html' %}
{% block content %}
<h1>hello</h1>

    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="text-align: left ; border-color: black;" id="pizza_table">
        <tbody>
            {% for item in items %}
                <td>
                    {{ item.name }}
                    <p>{{ item.details }}</p>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <img src="{{item.item_logo}}">
                </td>
                <td>

                </td>
                <td>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" style="margin: 5px ;" onclick="additem('Seafood Pizza', 20 ) ;">Add</button>
                </td>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>

{% endblock %}
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Qoute from the [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.storage):

> Using a FileField or an ImageField (see below) in a model takes a few steps:
>
> In your settings file, you’ll need to define MEDIA_ROOT as the full path to a directory where you’d like Django to store uploaded files. (For performance, these files are not stored in the database.) Define MEDIA_URL as the base public URL of that directory. Make sure that this directory is writable by the Web server’s user account.
>
> Add the FileField or ImageField to your model, defining the upload_to option to specify a subdirectory of MEDIA_ROOT to use for uploaded files.
>
> All that will be stored in your database is a path to the file (relative to MEDIA_ROOT). You’ll most likely want to use the convenience url attribute provided by Django. For example, if your ImageField is called mug_shot, you can get the absolute path to your image in a template with {{ object.mug_shot.url }}.

Also you need to modify urls to serve media files during [development](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development).

So you need to add `MEDIA_ROOT` and `MEDIA_URL` in your settings file:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Add to urls file this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

and add `url` method inside template:

```
<img src="{{item.item_logo.url}}">
```

Comment: do I have to change the upload_to path in my code ?

Comment: @AliZain you can. upload_to value will be appended with MEDIA_ROOT. So if MEDIA_ROOT is '/usr/local' and upload_to is '/images' your files will be stored inside '/usr/local/images'.

Comment: I must be missing something , when I add + static in urls file it shows errors on words static and settings

Comment: You need to import this: `from django.conf import settings   
from django.conf.urls.static import static`. Check example https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development